# SPFx resolving dependency issues

Tags: npm, spfx

While following this training unit by Microsoft
[Exercise - Use the SPFx PnP reusable property pane controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/sharepoint-spfx-web-part-property-pane/7-exercise-pnp-controls) I encounter errors, any advice on how to resolve these issues?

#### Environment Info

- Platform: Windows
- nodeJS v16.18.1
- npm 8.19.2
- gulp CLI version: 2.3.0
- gulp Local version: 4.0.2
- yeoman 4.3.1
- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.16.1

#### Problem

When I execute the following command

```
  npm install @pnp/spfx-property-controls --save --save-exact
```

I get this output:

```
    npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
    npm WARN While resolving: react-ace@5.8.0
    npm WARN Found: react@17.0.1
    npm WARN node_modules/@pnp/spfx-property-controls/node_modules/react
    npm WARN   react@"17.0.1" from @pnp/spfx-property-controls@3.11.0
    npm WARN   node_modules/@pnp/spfx-property-controls
    npm WARN     @pnp/spfx-property-controls@"*" from the root project
    npm WARN   6 more (@microsoft/sp-core-library, ...)
    npm WARN
    npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
    npm WARN peer react@"^0.13.0 || ^0.14.0 || ^15.0.1 || ^16.0.0" from react-ace@5.8.0
    npm WARN node_modules/@pnp/spfx-property-controls/node_modules/react-ace
    npm WARN   react-ace@"5.8.0" from @pnp/spfx-property-controls@3.11.0
    npm WARN   node_modules/@pnp/spfx-property-controls
    npm WARN
    npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
    npm WARN node_modules/react
    npm WARN   peer react@"^0.13.0 || ^0.14.0 || ^15.0.1 || ^16.0.0" from react-ace@5.8.0
    npm WARN   node_modules/@pnp/spfx-property-controls/node_modules/react-ace
    npm WARN     react-ace@"5.8.0" from @pnp/spfx-property-controls@3.11.0
    npm WARN     node_modules/@pnp/spfx-property-controls
    npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
    npm WARN While resolving: react-ace@5.8.0
    npm WARN Found: react-dom@17.0.1
    npm WARN node_modules/@pnp/spfx-property-controls/node_modules/react-dom
    npm WARN   react-dom@"17.0.1" from @pnp/spfx-property-controls@3.11.0
    npm WARN   node_modules/@pnp/spfx-property-controls
    npm WARN     @pnp/spfx-property-controls@"*" from the root project
    npm WARN   5 more (@microsoft/sp-core-library, ...)
    npm WARN
    npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
    npm WARN peer react-dom@"^0.13.0 || ^0.14.0 || ^15.0.1 || ^16.0.0" from react-ace@5.8.0
    npm WARN node_modules/@pnp/spfx-property-controls/node_modules/react-ace
    npm WARN   react-ace@"5.8.0" from @pnp/spfx-property-controls@3.11.0
    npm WARN   node_modules/@pnp/spfx-property-controls
    npm WARN
    npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react-dom@16.14.0
    npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
    npm WARN   peer react-dom@"^0.13.0 || ^0.14.0 || ^15.0.1 || ^16.0.0" from react-ace@5.8.0
    npm WARN   node_modules/@pnp/spfx-property-controls/node_modules/react-ace
    npm WARN     react-ace@"5.8.0" from @pnp/spfx-property-controls@3.11.0
    npm WARN     node_modules/@pnp/spfx-property-controls

    added 50 packages, and audited 2693 packages in 53s

    171 packages are looking for funding
      run `npm fund` for details

    86 vulnerabilities (30 moderate, 47 high, 9 critical)
```

After performing the edits to the default project template as described in the tutorial `gulp serve` is successful - no errors, but the workbench displays an error (several other errors in dev tools as well)

[image]

The `componentId`
in message:

*Manifest not found for component id "0d910c1c-13b9-4e1c-9aa4-b008c5e42d7d" and version "17.0.2".* refers to react components.

```
    {
      "componentId": "0d910c1c-13b9-4e1c-9aa4-b008c5e42d7d",
      "componentName": "react",
      "componentVersion": "17.0.1",
      "isDirectDependency": false
    },
    {
      "componentId": "0d910c1c-13b9-4e1c-9aa4-b008c5e42d7d",
      "componentName": "react",
      "componentVersion": "17.0.2",
      "isDirectDependency": true
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.